# How to Setup graphlql-upload for Meteor with Apollo

Tags: file, meteor, upload, apollo

I setup meteor and apollo as follows.

```
 const server = new ApolloServer({
    playground: true,
    schema,
    plugins: [
      ...
    ],
    context: async({req}) => ({
      user: await getUser(req.headers.authorization) 
    })  
  });  

  await server.start();

  server.applyMiddleware({
    app: WebApp.connectHandlers,
    cors: true,
    path: '/graphql',
  });
```

But I don’t know how to set graphql-upload.
(https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads/)

If you know how to setup graphql-upload in a meteor with apollo environment, please help.

Comment: The link shows how to upload a file. What exactly is your problem? Do you need to move files to DB?